# MacOS Finder's "find" doesn't find webpages of type: .mhtml

Tags: macos, finder

I noticed even if I am in a folder with say "joe.mhtml", and search using Finder "find" doesn't find the file and any other .mhtml files. However, spotlight search can find it for me.

[image]

Now if I set the search to "This Mac" if find them all!

[image]
Is it because it is not indexed? How can I fix this, please?

Comment: Wrong  site, I'm afraid. You're looking for [apple.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Comment: Thank you. I thought stackoverflow direct me to that automatically. But it didn't!

Comment: No problem. Please delete the question here before posting to the other site. :-)